# Apache POI Word insert both table and text at the same level

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to insert both a table and some text at the same level in a XWPFDocument using Apache POI, meaning that the table will be on the left side and the text on it'r right side, just like in this template:

[image]

Using a solution providing a cursor found around, does not seems to make it work. This is the approach commonly used:

```
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("col one");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col two");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("col three");

XmlCursor cursor = table.getCTTbl().newCursor();
cursor.toEndToken();

while(cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
XWPFParagraph paragraph2 = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);

XWPFRun run = paragraph2.createRun();
run.setText("Abstract: ");
```

The result is this:

[image]

Do you have any idea there is a way to make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `XmlCursor` is the wrong way here. An `XmlCursor` gets used to get or insert XML into a special position of an XML document. But what you need is either a table property (text wrapping) or a page setting (multiple columns on page).

To get a page spiltted into two columns, see [How to add continuous section break to XWPFDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166883/how-to-add-continuous-section-break-to-xwpfdocument/41188851#41188851). There left side also may contain a table.

To set table properties, which not are available using [XWPFTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html) one can do the following:

Create a `*.docx` document having the setting. See [Set or change table properties](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/set-or-change-table-properties-3237de89-b287-4379-8e0c-86d94873b2e0#__toc1) for how to set table text wrapping.

Unzip the  `*.docx`  file (each Office Open XML file is simply a ZIP archive) and have a look into `/word/document.xml`. You will find something like

```xml
<w:tbl>
 <w:tblPr>
  <w:tblpPr w:vertAnchor="text"/>
  <w:tblOverlap w:val="never"/>
 ...
 </w:tblPr>
 ...
</w:tbl>
```

for table XML.

That are [TableProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tableproperties?view=openxml-3.0.1) having [TablePositionProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tablepositionproperties?view=openxml-3.0.1) and [TableOverlap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.tableoverlap?view=openxml-3.0.1).

Now recreate this using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTableTextWrapping {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Text before table...");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable(1, 3);
  table.setWidth("50%");
  
  //set table text wrapping
  //get table properties, add new table position properties, set vertical anchor Text
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblpPr().setVertAnchor​(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVAnchor.TEXT);
  //get table properties, add new table overlap, set value Never
  table.getCTTbl().getTblPr().addNewTblOverlap().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STTblOverlap.NEVER);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Text after table...");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordTableTextWrapping.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```